# pgfgantt Milestone horizontal position

Tags: pgfgantt, charts

If one uses `pgfgantt` package in a standard way, the horizontal position of milestone is between "month" columns.
Is it possible to make it appear ON the "month" column?
I would like to avoid a weird situation when the milestone on the last month crosses the border of the chart as well as make accent that something
is going to be done **during** some month rather that **at the end** of it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid,
hgrid,
]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{12} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `east` anchor (ans possibly an `xshift`) for the `milestone` style:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid,
hgrid,
milestone/.append style={anchor=east,xshift=-1pt},
]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{12} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best solution in my opinion is to use the milestone shift option provide by the package.

Note that the default values are a left shift of 0.6 and a right shift of 0.4, so adjusting both by -0.5 gives the values used. If you don't want it in the middle or if you want to stretch the marker then adjust as appropriate.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
    milestone left shift=.1,
    milestone right shift=-.1
    ]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{12} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latex output]